# Excel pivot table loses max & min columns on refresh

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a pivot table built on a data model fed by a power query. There are 3 columns based on the 'date period' field - max of date period, min of date period, and distinct count of date period. When the power query & pivot table are refreshed, the max & min columns disappear, but the distinct count column remains.

I've not been able to pin down what changes in the data trigger this - it's when additional rows are added to the data source, but not all additions result in the columns disappearing.

Any suggestions for where I can look next to resolve this?

Comment: Do the field names used in the max and min change?

Comment: The field names all remain the same and the only change is additional rows of data added, typically with 1 additional date beyond the existing date range. The distinct count is using the same field name as the max & min.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.